# XeLaTex, \includegraphics, and spaces in filepath

Tags: xetex, includegraphics

I am using XeLaTeX and need to include graphics wherein the filepath has spaces in it.

I am trying to use the `grffile` package to help with the space issue; nothing else works without error. But when I compile

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{C:/Users/Gregory/Box Sync/An Introduction to Mathematical Modeling/figures/figlinear1}
\end{document}
```

there are no errors/warnings, the graphic appears, BUT there is also the line printed with the image `Sync/An Introduction to Mathematical Modeling/figures/figlinear1.bb`. Clearly it is referencing the last part of the path after the first space.

My questions are "Why is this happening?"; "What's the deal with the `.bb` extension?"; "What do I do to fix this?"

I'm running XeLaTex from TeXLive 2019 on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Is your tex system up-to-date? If yes remove \usepackage{grffile} and try again.

Comment: Might be an idea to specify what file type you are including

Comment: In current latex grffile.sty is an empty file and does nothing it may be needed in older releases.  But do you have to specify the path with spaces at all?  `\includegraphics{C:/Users/Gregory/Box Sync/An Introduction to Mathematical Modeling/figures/figlinear1}`  makes the document source non-portable even if it works,  it would be more normal to just have `\includegraphics{figlinear1}` and have the image in your input path (or the same folder as the document)

Comment: This is my tex system: XeTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991; pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20.   With `grffile`, pdfLaTeX works, but not without. I just realized that  XeLaTeX gives the same result (as described above) with/out `grffile`. And I'm including a .pdf.

Comment: it is the version of latex that is important not the version of xetex, but if grffile does anything at all you must have a release from last year or earlier but it means that it may not work with spaces as grffile was (last year) broken by underlying changes to latex to support spaces in filenames, so as all its important functionality is incorporated into latex the file was made an empty stub that does nothing. so without knowing which release you have, the simplest thing is to avoid spaces and just have `\includegraphics{figlinear1.pdf}` with that file in the same folder as your document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm updating my tex system now to see if that changes anything. And yes, putting the image file in the same/sub directory as the main is far simpler. However, there is an external constraint of using Box Sync, and pdfLaTeX and Box Sync seem to fight over control of a file sometimes meaning it is hard to run the main file when it is in a Box folder. I'm trying to manage a work-around; all files but the main (which gets resaved, etc.) are in Box.

Comment: After running `tlmgr update --all`, the problem is resolved. I can include graphics along filepaths with spaces with both pdflatex and xelatex without a special package or using quotation marks.